# Can I reduce drag with channeling freestream air at the backward facing surface?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

Idea is to increase static pressure at backward facing surface to reduce drag.

Can I reduce drag with channeling freestream air  at the backward facing surface, like picture suggest?

[image]

Comment: I suppose there would be a so big pressure loss in the pipes virtually neglecting any benefit

Comment: Is the flow within those pipes turbulent? How much drag happens within them? The wing works by having lower pressure above the wing than below, but this drawing seems to introduce air of equal pressure to both top & bottom, which ought to reduce total lift, requiring more AoA to compensate. Not seeing the positive value here, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of close conceptually, but from a practical point of view taking space from the fuselage or wing structure for plumbing may not work out.

But this thinking is on the right track.  The rearward portions of aircraft structure are where the boundary layer can become more and more turbulent, increasing drag.

"Blowing" these regions can lead to reductions in drag, leading to improvements in fuel economy.

Props have been mounted on the trailing edges of [wings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-36_Peacemaker) and/or [fuselage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_335), and jet engines placed on [aft portion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_727) of the fuselage can also help "clean up" the air flow.

Related reading [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167610523001320).  Application: drag reduction high speed trains.